# ObjectMapper doesn't map child entities recursively

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectmapper

I have an entity framework entity:

```
[Table("Dienst")]
public class Dienst
{
    ...
    public IList<Dienst> Diensten { get; set; }
}
```

And a corresponding DienstDto like:

```
public class DienstDto : BaseDto
{    
    public List<DienstDto> Diensten { get; set; }
}
```

Objectmapper config is:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
        cfg.CreateMap<Dienst, DienstDto>().ReverseMap();               
});
```

Then, if I retrieve the diensten using entity framework like:

```
var diensten = _dienstRepository.Get().Include("Diensten"));
```

Then I get back the full hierarchy of diensten and its child diensten, and for each child dienst again its child diensten, 5 levels deep. This is correct.

However, if I project this using AutoMapper to the dto's, with:

```
 var result = diensten.ProjectTo<DienstDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
```

...then the resulting mapping only contains diensten en 1 level of child diensten, but the rest of the child diensten is not mapped.

Does ObjectMapper not support recursive mapping of child entities x levels deep or am I missing something?

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build. And you can remove the `Include`. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3349 That's for EF Core, EF6 doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks... this project is not using core... so i guess I will have to map it manually then.

Comment: You could try that setting, just in case, but I would expect an error from EF.

Comment: If that doesn't work out, of course you can always use `Map` instead. no need for manual mapping.